# how to set chromedriver work for centos 6.6 to run selenium test cases in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, centos6

I have download and tried all the version of the chromedriver in my centos 6.6 version to run selenium.

I Have followed this: 
http://selftechy.com/2011/08/17/running-selenium-tests-with-chromedriver-on-linux

i am getting the error like below:

```
./chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./chromedriver)
```

I am trying to run this python test script:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/intel/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml')
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Comment: what selenium version are you using, and what chromedriver version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was that I downloaded a prebuilt chromedriver RPM for CentOS 6 at http://downloads.onrooby.com/chromium/rpms/ which placed the executable at /opt/chromium-browser/chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Its a known bug,
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=440
solution is suggested at https://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/