# Error on running chromedriver in CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, centos6

I tried `chmod+x chromedriver` and `chmod 777 chromedriver` then `./chromedriver`

it throws error:

> /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required
>   by ./chromedriver) /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:version 'CXXABI_1.3.5'
>   not found (required by ./chromedriver)
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required
>   by ./chromedriver)

Any idea to to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800257/how-to-set-chromedriver-work-for-centos-6-6-to-run-selenium-test-cases-in-python

Comment: Thank you @Jimatw

Comment: I upgraded to CentOS 7 and use the latest chrome driver 2.29. Ant it works! :)

Comment: Faced same issue, I think chromedriver is not supported in Centos

Comment: @aniruddha, it was fixed when I upgraded CentOS 7 and Chrome driver to latest.

Comment: hi @joan, you are right, its works in Centos 7, but Centos 6 does not have support to it, unfortunately I am bound to use Centos 6 due to organizational restrictions, thinking about try to use firefox driver