# /opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver) using chromium browser on linux

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am trying to  run the selenium  testcase using chromium browser in linux ..

Step to  setup  chromium  browser in  linux :

downloaded the chrome-linux.zip  from the below path and extract in the linux machine in some specific path

https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/572137/chrome-linux.zip

Put the latest  chromedriver linux version file(2.40) in the linux  machine

full permission(777)  has been given to chromedrive  file aswell as the chrome-linux folder also.

And the selenium  code :

```
WebDriver driver =  null;
DesiredCapabilities caps =  DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
opts.addArguments("--headless");
opts.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
opts.setBinary("/opt/chromeos/chrome-linux/chrome");//path of the chrome application file in linux 
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opts);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/chromeos/chomedriver");//path of the chromedriver file in linux
driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

When I am trying to  run  I am getting unreachable browser exception .

```
/opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver)
/opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver)
/opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver)
Jul 03, 2018 12:46:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'ION-MUM-PreQA-JB-61-75', ip: '10.10.61.75', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
        at com.DemoChromiumTest.main(DemoChromiumTest.java:24)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'ION-MUM-PreQA-JB-61-75', ip: '10.10.61.75', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:178)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:16689/status] to be available after 20012 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:175)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
        ... 11 more
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
/opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver)
/opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver)
/opt/chromeos/chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/chromeos/chromedriver)
Jul 03, 2018 12:46:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session due to missing **GLIBC_2.15** and/or **GLIBC_2.14**.

First of all, as per the your question details as you are using *Selenium Java Client v2.53.0* I don't see any issue with your code block. However as you are on *Linux OS* instead of **chrome-linux.zip** you must ensure that you downloaded **chrome-linux.tar** / **chrome-linux.tz** and untarred it for proper usage.

---

### What went wrong

> `/lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found` and `/lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found`

The *ChromeDriver* binary you are trying to execute was built on a `GLIBC-2.15` based system which will not get executed on any system with older GLIBC.

> `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found`

Similarly, the *ChromeDriver* binary you are trying to execute was built on a `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` based system which will not get executed on any system with older GLIBC where as your GLIBC is older than 2.14.

---

### tl;dr

Look out at [**DistroWatch.com**](https://distrowatch.com/) for compatible binaries.

---

### Possible Solutions

Further, you haven't mentioned your exact environment details still here are some of the possible reasons and solutions:

- As per [**Error on running chromedriver in CentOS 6.6**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948023/error-on-running-chromedriver-in-centos-6-6) if you are using `CentOS` below **version 7**, upgrading to `CentOS version 7` will solve your issue.
- As per [chromedriver_linux64_2.1.zip not working in CentOS 6.4 (latest)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=440) you need to:

  - Download latest chrome for CentOS6.4 ( http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/ )
  - Download latest ChromeDriver (2.40) .
  - Now go to `/opt/google/chrome` folder (You need sudo access).
  - Copy `chromedriver` to this folder (this is for simplication you can have it anywhere).
  - Create a copy of `google-chrome` as `google-chromedriver`. vi google-chromedriver and last line modify as:

    ```
     exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chromedriver"  "$@"  (you can provide custom location of driver too).
    ```
  - Include in path

    ```
    sudo ln  -s /opt/google/chrome/google-chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
    ```
  - Change the permission:

    ```
    chmod +x chromedriver
    ```